# How to automate git pull on the local system whenever there is a change in the remote GitHub repository?

Tags: python, git, github, github-api

There is a remote GitHub repository where everyone makes changes to files, raises PR and updates it regularly. I have the same repository in my local. Right now am doing git pull manually whenever I see changes in the remote repository. Instead of manually doing it every time, I just want whatever the changes that are happening in the remote repository to automatically replicate in my local via a python API if possible.

I wanted to know if it is possible for a python script to automatically detect changes whenever there is a change/development in the corresponding remote GitHub repository and update those changes at a certain time in the local folder. So that I don't have to keep doing a manual git pull operation whenever I see changes in the remote GitHub repository.

Comment: Yes, that's possible. You can use `git diff` for that. Also, I think this is not appropriate to make this process automated because of potential conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

Automating `git pull` is a bad idea because it would fail whenever there is a conflict.

Some people use cron jobs for running `git fetch` implicitly in the background, but it introduces other complications that you might not want to deal with. From the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push):

> A general note on safety: supplying this option without an expected value, i.e. as `--force-with-lease` or `--force-with-lease=<refname>` interacts very badly with anything that implicitly runs `git fetch` on the remote to be pushed to in the background, e.g. `git fetch origin` on your repository in a cronjob.